# ruby gem compass installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, compass

I am trying to install `gem` `compass`, but I am getting the following error while running `sudo gem install compass`

```
Fetching: sass-3.4.22.gem (100%)
Fetching: multi_json-1.12.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: compass-core-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: compass-import-once-1.0.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: chunky_png-1.3.8.gem (100%)
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.8.gem (100%)
Fetching: ffi-1.9.14.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.14 for inspection.
```

Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out

My gem version is `1.8.23`

Answer (score 0):

please try this first.

```
xcode-select --install
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install compass
```

If this not working then

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby
apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2(Change from your ruby version)
sudo gem install compass
```